# Need help to draw the following picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

How to draw the following picture in latex? I do not have much experience in tikz, could anyone kindly help? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: You can start here - https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ:_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_1)%E2%80%94Basic_Drawing

Comment: @nidhin Thanks for the information! I looked at it and I can only draw a line. I do not know how to add nodes and the shaded vertical line. Could you help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

With using `pattern` and `positioning` libraries from the  `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, node contents={}}
                    ]
\path[pattern=north east lines] (0,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\draw   (-3,0) -- (-2,0) node (a) [dot] 
               -- ( 0,0) node     [dot]
               -- ( 2,0) node (b) [dot]
               -- (3,0);
\draw   (0,1)   -- (0,-1) coordinate (aux);
\path   (a |- aux) node[below] {$Z_{P\hat{N}}$}
        (aux)      node[below] {$Z_{P\hat{N}+1}$}
        (b |- aux) node[below] {$Z_{P\hat{N}+2}$};           
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```